# How to count entries per day in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, count

I have a csv file with the download times of various files and I want to know the number of files that was download per day.

Code:

```
with open('hello.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    list1=list(readCSV)
    count=0
    b=-1
    for j in list1:
        b=b+1
        if b>0:
            dt=j[1]
            dt_obj=parse(dt)
            d=dt_obj.date()
            if dt==d:
                count+=1
            else:
                print(count)
                break
```

`hello.csv` is my csv file. I have date times so I use the parser to get the date. I want to have the number of downloads per day. I know that this code can't work but I don't know how to compare if the next entry is the same date or not..

My date times look like "2004-01-05 17:56:46" and are in the second column of the csv file. When I have 7 entries on 2004-01-05 and 5 on 2004-01-06 the vector count should look like count=[7 5] for example

Comment: you really should provide a short excerpt of your input file and the desired output...

Comment: I added an example

Comment: not really... you described what the files look like.please post a few lines of the file so people trying to help can run tests and do not have to guess the contents of your file. and:  are the dates sorted in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below procedure.

- Convert to a datetime object.
- Create a column containing only the date (remove the time).
- Group by the new date column.
- Count the objects.

```
# Read csv file
data = pd.read_csv('hello.csv')

# Converting to datetime object
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])

# Creating date column
data['date'] = data['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.date())

# Grouping by date
data.group_by('date')['column'].count()

# Result
date
2019-05-20    4
2019-05-21    3
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Correct but pandas is overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Pandas. Say your date column is called `date`. Since your `date` is a datetime object, you can group by dates and use the `transform` method

```py
df = pd.read_csv('hello.csv')
df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date).normalize()
df['count'] = df.groupby('date')['date'].transform('count')
df = df[['date','count']]
```

Now you have a new dataframe with what you want.

Comment: The data contains time up to the second. Your answer does not take that into account.

Comment: I only become ones because 'date' is a datetime.. how can I get the dates from the datetimes before?

Comment: yes like @SergeBallesta I forgot the date parser to keep only the day. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I added the line to take off the time

Comment: ok that works! But now I have for each column of the csv files the number of the entries for the date (I became the date in the first column and then the same number in the next 4 columns) is there a way where I became a vector with only the date and the number of the entries?

Comment: my columns look like         
"0     2004-01-05 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001"
I just want to have "2004-01-05   1"

Comment: I can't explain where 1970-01-01 come from and why the counts have the format 00:00:00.000000001

Comment: can you provide please a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to count elements, Python collections module provides the `Counter` class which can be used as a dictionary `{element_name: count}`. I will assume that your `parse` function does what you want. The code can simply be:

```
with open('hello.csv', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    counter = collections.Counter((parse(row[1]).date() for row in readCSV))
print(counter)
```

With your expected data, it should print:

```
Counter({'2004-01-05': 7, '2004-01-06': 5})
```